# making multiple calls to Digest Update in OpenSSL

Tags: c, hash, openssl

I have read that in order to send a big data to be hashed using EVP_Digest calls, one can call EVP_DIgestUpdate multiple times.

I need to call EVP_Update and obtain the partially computed hash out and then send the rest of the input (along with the partially computed hash) to compute the entire hash of the input..

I have written the following code to test:

```
 int try()
 {
 EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
 const EVP_MD *md;
 //char data[] = "Test Message\n";
 unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
 unsigned int md_len, i;
 char *data = "test";

 OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

 md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256");

 if(!md) {
        printf("Unknown message digest\n");
        exit(1);
 }
 EVP_MD_CTX_init(&ctx);
 EVP_DigestInit_ex(&ctx, md, NULL);
 EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, data, strlen(data));
 //EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, toB64val, strlen(toB64val));
 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&ctx, md_value, &md_len); //retrieve digest from ctx unto md_value and #bytes written is copied into md_len


 EVP_MD_CTX newctx;
  //char data[] = "Test Message\n";
  unsigned char new_md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
  unsigned int new_md_len;

  EVP_MD_CTX_init(&newctx);
  EVP_DigestInit_ex(&newctx, md, NULL);
 char *newdata = " message";
 printf("md_len = %d\n", md_len);
 int newlen = md_len;
 EVP_DigestUpdate(&newctx, md_value, 32);
 EVP_DigestUpdate(&newctx, newdata, strlen(data));
 //EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, toB64val, strlen(toB64val));
 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&newctx, new_md_value, &new_md_len);

 EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&newctx);

 printf("Digest is: ");
 for(i = 0; i < new_md_len; i++) printf("%02x", new_md_value[i]);
 printf("\n");

 return 0;

 }
```

I am trying to compute hash (sha256) for "test message" as my input.
However, I need to be able to retrieve "partially computed hash" of"test" and then by giving it again to another new context compute for the entire input.

However the hash o "test message" as computed separately doesnt match. can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SHA256 block size is 64 bytes, so you can only get a meaningful partial hash on 64-byte boundaries of the input message.  Internally, the EVP is buffering the message until it gets 64 bytes.

When a hash result is requested, the message is padded with a 1-bit, followed by 0-bits, followed by 64-bits of message length (in bits) to make it a multiple of 64 bytes.

So, the first hash you compute is over the message:

```
{"test", 1'b1, 415'b0, 64'h32}
```

Second, even if your partial message was a multiple of 64 bytes, you can't just pass the partial hash as data to the new hash.  Assuming you meant to pass `strlen(newdata)` instead of `strlen(data)` in the last call to `EVP_DigestUpdate`, the hash you would have computed would be over the padded 320-bit message:

```
{<32-byte hash>, " message", 1'b1, 127'b0, 64'h320}
```

Which is not the same as the hash of the padded 96-bit message:

```
{"test message", 1'b1, 351'b0, 64'h96}
```

In order to continue a partial hash, the hash state (`A B C D E F G H`) must be saved and restored (not sure if EVP provides an API for this).  Because your partial message is so short, the hash state will not have been updated from the initial, and the message residue (the part at the end that didn't complete a block) will be sitting in a buffer inside the EVP context, waiting for more data to make up a block.  So, in addition to the hash state, you would also need to save and restore the message residue.

Comment: Thanks. With how many zeros is the digest padded? I  don't quite follow your notation. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I used verilog syntax.  The terms in braces are bit vectors that are concatenated left to right.  The leading number on a term is its width in bits, the `'b` or `'h` indicate binary or hex, and the digits after that are the value.  The message is always terminated with a 1 bit, followed by 0's followed by 64 bits of message length (in bits). The number of zeros between the 1 and the length are the smallest number that makes the result a whole multiple of 512 bits (the block size).

Comment: Are you planning on doing anything with the partial hash other than using it to complete the final hash?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the "partial digest", you might make a copy of the `EVP_MD_CTX`, and then get the digest from the copy.  Thus:

```
EVP_MD_CTX ctx, partial_ctx;

/* ... call EVP_DigestUpdate() several times... */
EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, data, data_len);

/* Now, we're going to get the digest up thus far, without
 * interrupting/changing the final digest, by making a copy of ctx,
 * and using the copy to get the partial digest.
 */
EVP_MD_CTX_init(&partial_ctx);
EVP_MD_CTX_copy(&partial_ctx, &ctx);
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&partial_ctx, partial_md_value, &partial_md_len);

/* Don't forget to cleanup the partial ctx. */
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&partial_ctx);

/* Continue digesting more data to get the final digest. */
EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, data, data_len);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot.As i understand, i only need this ctx structure. Can i convert it to some void pointer and maybe get the partial digeßt from the ctx? How can this be done?

Comment: When you call `EVP_DigestFinal_ex()`, you change the state maintained by the `EVP_MD_CTX`.  That's why you do need _both_ the full `ctx`, and the copied `partial_ctx`, in order to achieve what you want.